# Filezilla Server on VMware

Tags: filezilla

I'm running a Windows 10 virtual machine on VMware. My Host machine is a Mac OSX. I have installed a FileZilla Server on the Windows machine and a FileZilla Client on the Mac OSX system.
I want to simulate internet access (not LAN access) from the FileZilla Client to the FileZilla Server.
Anyone has some suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the Guest machine with a NAT connection. That will put the guest machine on a different subnet from the Host machine.

That will normally suffice for what you are doing because the Filezilla client on the Host will access the guest Server as if it were a completely different machine.

You can change the NAT subnet if you wish using the VMware Network Editor.

Comment: Thank you very much! That works! Certainly, I had to open ports in the fw of the guest machine running the server.